# Is there a redirect bug on migrated questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have spotted a strange behaviour and I think it is a bug. I have found this question:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836364/what-is-the-solution-of-these-errors`

I have made it not clickable, since it goes to the wrong question anyway. It was on Stack Overflow, and has been migrated to Database Administrators. It redirects to the following question, which is plainly the wrong one (different text, wrong user):

[dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9458/ora-32004-obsolete-or-deprecated-parameters-specified-for-rdbms-instance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9458/ora-32004-obsolete-or-deprecated-parameters-specified-for-rdbms-instance)

The question does appear to exist if the terrible title is searched for (at the time of writing it is at the top in each case):

- [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3awhat%20is%20the%20solution%20of%20these%20errors%3f) (shows its migrated status)
- [on Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3awhat%20is%20the%20solution%20of%20these%20errors%3f) (appears to have migrated)

I am not worried about the question itself - I have no idea if it is good or bad since it is not possible to view it. However, the dodgy redirect probably needs looking into.

Comment: You very first link seems to work fine, now (and redirect correctly): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836364/what-is-the-solution-of-these-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836364/what-is-the-solution-of-these-errors)

Comment: Link to the original question (noredirect): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836364/what-is-the-solution-of-these-errors?noredirect=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836364/what-is-the-solution-of-these-errors?noredirect=1)

Comment: Thanks @ypercubeᵀᴹ: the redirect is changed and correct now for me. It was an issue yesterday too, but perhaps a cache expired or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I open the SO link while not logged in, I end up at the "wrong" question, the one you linked first, i.e. [ORA-32004: obsolete or deprecated parameter(s) specified for RDBMS instance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9458/ora-32004-obsolete-or-deprecated-parameters-specified-for-rdbms-instance)

However, when I am logged in and click the SO link, I am redirected to this DBA.SE question: [what is the solution of these errors?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209531/what-is-the-solution-of-these-errors)

The latter is closed as a duplicate of the former.

So here is what I believe is happening. Redirection for migrated questions works automatically both when you are logged in and when you are not logged in at the time of clicking the link. If you are not logged in, you will also be [automatically redirected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125807) if you click on a question closed as a duplicate.

Now, if a question is migrated and then closed as a duplicate at the destination site, you will be redirected twice if you click the original link while not logged in (at least if you are not logged in at the destination site).

Comment: Ah, good sleuthing - thanks! So the redirect was going automatically to the dupe target on the DBA site. I expect that's deliberate, but I wonder if it is a bit confusing?

Comment: @halfer: I found it a little confusing the first time I encountered it, but for me it was so mostly because it was unexpected. I'd never experienced that before as I'd always clicked duplicate questions whilst logged in. Wikipedia shows a nice little "Redirected from..." notice, which I find helpful. Perhaps it would make sense for SE to adopt something like that.

Comment: Fair enough. I agree with the cross-site redirect, but not the dup redirect - I think an extra click is not a major price for a potentially less confusing UX. I'll see if this question can tempt a SE employee to comment.

Comment: @halfer [Automatically redirect anonymous user from unanswered duplicate question to corresponding answered version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125807)

Comment: Aha, thanks @PaulWhite - it is a "feature" `:-)`.